# I am either the cause or effect of devastation

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> I am either the cause or effect of devastation
>   Drop a letter, I may serve, judge or contain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am either the cause or effect of devastation

> crater - the mouth of a volcano, or a hollow created by a meteorite impact

Drop a letter, I may serve, judge or contain.

> cater - to serve, rater - a judge, crate - a container

Comment: Tom, you never cease to amaze me.

Answer (score 3):

It could be

> DEVALUATION

Because

> Devastation can be caused by the value of something going down or 
>  Devaluation of money can be caused by devastation
>  EVALUATION can be a judgement of something, or contain a judgement...Not sure about serve though.
>  EDIT - I suppose an evaluation could serve as a tool by which to use as a plan for improving things.

Comment: Not close I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% satisfied with this, but perhaps you are

> a COUP, which (1) might well be the cause of devastation as the new regime eliminates its enemies and (2) might well be the effect of devastation as such things often happen when a society has been destabilized by e.g. losing a war;

and removing a letter might yield

> a COP who both serves (the public) and judges (criminal guilt, although of course others have the last word on that) and a CUP (which contains liquid).

-- OR --

(I'm not 100% satisfied with this one either) you might be

> a REEF, which might cause a shipwreck or be formed by one

and losing a letter would yield

> a REF(eree) who both serves and judges, and a REF(erence) as in computing which kinda-sorta contains something else. (This last one isn't very satisfactory since usually you want to distinguish between something that merely *refers* and something that actually *contains*.)

Comment: You are welcome to try again :)